# wsl (ubuntu) to Ganache GUI on windows 10 Network Connection Error

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, decentralized-exchange

Am using wsl(ubuntu) on windows 10.
Problem is, am trying to deploy.js file with node,  here's the error result --> `("  reason: 'could not detect network',   code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',   event: 'noNetwork'  using  ganache network)`

Answer (score 0):

Activate your Ganache, and navigate to "contract"...scroll-down and click-on "link truffle projects , accept the allow your system to have access to Ganache on the pop-up and afterward follow the same procedure and continue by clicking on link-truffle projects then go  to server and finally change server host-name to "vEHTHERNET(WSL)".

Answer (score 0):

✅ANSWERED

to use Ganache on both Windows and WSL from ganache GUI of Windows.

**1**: **goto your ganache setting > Server > HOSTNAME.**

**2**: Set Value to 0.0.0.0 - All Interfaces
[image]

now in WSL web3 app, you need to provide `specific Ip Address instead of 127.0.0.1`
so to find that address use this command *(bash command in ubuntu)*

```
grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'
```

and use that IP to write your RPC URL for WSL based connection like this

`let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(http://172.19.192.1:7545);`